# Blackstaff Apprentice and Wizard's Fury

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, theme

I looked around online, but again couldn't find an answer. I also saw the Dragon Magazine articles from issues 409 and 374, but want a diffinative ruling.

When you take the Blackstaff Apprentice theme, it says you learn Magic Missile (if you did not already have it) *and* once per encounter you can use it as a minor action instead of a standard.

Wizard's Fury Power says you must know Magic Missile (as a wizard at-will) and can use it once per turn as a a minor action.

Can the two be used together for a missile each turn this way, or does the theme power override this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason why not.

From [Blackstaff Apprentice](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=981),

> **Blackstaff Apprentice Starting Feature (1st level):** You gain the magic missile power if you do not already have it. Once per encounter you can use magic missile as a minor action instead of a standard action.

[Wizard's Fury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7429) says

> Prerequisite: You must know the magic missile at-will wizard power.

You certainly know the power. I see no reason to disallow this combination. I'd even say that a Blackstaff Apprentice with Wizard's Fury active could, ***once***, use all three actions in a round to cast Magic Missile (normal standard action, minor from theme, minor from Wizard's Fury).

The theme requires you to be a wizard (who easily has access to Magic Missile anyway), so unless I'm missing something I don't see the potential for abuse.

Comment: Arcanist would have to burn an at-will spot to get it. This doesn't make sense as a theme for a Mage.

Comment: Right - Best case scenario is you're a wizard who doesn't get magic missile by default. You've then freed up a level 1 at-will slot since you don't have to take it. Otherwise all you're getting from the theme (at level 1, at least) is the encounter minor.

Comment: There is also a nice case if you're an MC wizard and want to take the wizard's fury power swap. you could get some mileage out of this that way

Comment: Sadly, Magic Missile is the only ranged spell that can be used as a basic ranged attack, so by using them together, I loose the ability to make multiple basic ranged attacks unless I get a projectile weapon to compensate (not good if there's a Warlord in the party, but fortunately, there isn't one in my party). I just need to reach level 9 so I can get Melf's Minute Meteors for three attacks per turn. >:)